# Generic Node POST request fails SOMETIMES?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Pretty generic MERN stack looking API i've built. All it does it when someone posts their data, which can be significantly large or small, it's sent to my DB.

However weirdly, I don't know why, it's now throwing errors about:

**UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: centralEmail is not defined**

I have no idea why as centralEmail is actually a field in a different schema and hence I have no idea why this is coming up...

My API is generic, see the:

```
//CREATE A ROLE DESC
router.post("/postlisting", async (req,res)=>{
  const newListing = new Rolelistings(req.body)
  console.log(req.body)

  try{
      const savedListing = await newListing.save();
      console.log('its working')
      res.status(200).json(savedListing)

  }catch(err){
      console.log('has failed while posting')
      res.status(500).json(err)
      console.log('check eroror log to see why')
  }
})
```

And my schema even more so.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

//CompanyProfileSchema
const RoleListings = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        role:{type:String, required: true, default: ""},
        companyListing:{type:String, required: false, default: ""},
        companyID:{type:String, required: false, default: ""},
        dateListing:{type:String, required: false, default: ""},
        status: {type: String, required: false},

        finalFormat:{type:String, required: false, default: ""},

        listingScore:{type: Number},
        companyEmail:{type:String},

        selectedStyle:{type:String, required: false, default: ""},
        selectedLocation:{type:String, required: false, default:""},
        selectedIndustry:{type:String, required: false},

        optionalMinSalaryRange:{type:String, required: false, default: ""},
        optionalMaxSalaryRange:{type:String, required: false, default: ""},
        optionalQuals:{type:String, required: false, default: ""},

        selectedInterview1:{type:String, required: false, default: ""},
        selectedInterview2:{type:String, required: false, default: ""},
        selectedInterview3:{type:String, required: false, default: ""},

        optionalSkills:{type:[String], required: false, default: []},

        optionalPerks:{type:[String], required: false, default: []},

        optionalWFH:{type:String, required: false, default: ""},

        optionalQuals:{type:[String], required: false, default: []},

        //
        lookingFor:{type:[String], required: false, default: []},
        dailyResponsibilites:{type:[String], required: false, default: []},
        FAQS:{type:[String], required: false, default: []},

        //
        requiredFields:{type:[String], required: false, default: []},

    },
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("RoleListings", RoleListings)
```

This is then connected to index.js like so:

```
//maintains the role listings, where the endpoint will be GET listings, or POST listing
app.use("/api/rolelisting", rolelistingsRoute)
```

Does anyone see an obvious error here? I have no idea if i'm missing something however the API throws this:

```
(node:18160) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: centralEmail is not defined
    at C:\ApplyWithin_repo_file\ApplyWithin\backend\routes\rolelistings.js:24:19
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:18160) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:18160) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Could you please show line 24 in `rolelistings.js`?

Comment: it shows that somewhere in your code you're trying to access a central email variable that is not defined.

Comment: Hi @KonradLinkowski please see the tag. I have updated my post to show it Also, it does not appear in the code. Weirdly, if I delete the only record in the .rolelistings DB, it will work. why would it only allow 1 record to be shown?

Comment: For me it looks like you are trying to us ea variable that is not defined